# How to view JSON logs of a managed VM in the Log Viewer?

Tags: google-app-engine, logging, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, fluentd

I'm trying to get JSON formatted logs on a Compute Engine VM instance to appear in the Log Viewer of the Google Developer Console. According to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging#cloud_logging_and_managed_vms_apps) it should be possible to do so:

> Applications using App Engine Managed VMs should write custom log
>   files to the VM's log directory at /var/log/app_engine/custom_logs.
>   These files are automatically collected and made available in the Logs
>   Viewer.
>
> Custom log files must have the suffix .log or .log.json. If the suffix
>   is .log.json, the logs must be in JSON format with one JSON object per
>   line. If the suffix is .log, log entries are treated as plain text.

This doesn't seem to be working for me: logs ending with `.log` are visible in the Log Viewer, but displayed as plain text. Logs ending with `.log.json` aren't visible at all.

It also contradicts another recent article that states that [file names must end in .log and its contents are treated as plain text](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/custom-runtimes#logging).

As far as I can tell Google uses [fluentd to index the log files](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-fluentd) into the Log Viewer. In the GitHub repository I cannot find any evidence that `.log.json` files are being indexed.

Does anyone know how to get this working? Or is the documentation out-of-date and has this feature been removed for some reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to generate JSON logs for the Managed VMs logviewer:

### The desired JSON format

The goal is to create a single line JSON object for each log line containing:

```json
{
    "message": "Error occurred!.",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "timestamp": {
        "seconds": 1437712034000,
        "nanos": 905
    }
}
```

(information sourced from Google: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11678#c5)

### Using python-json-logger

See: https://github.com/madzak/python-json-logger

```py
def get_timestamp_dict(when=None):
    """Converts a datetime.datetime to integer milliseconds since the epoch.

    Requires special handling to preserve microseconds.

    Args:
        when:
            A datetime.datetime instance. If None, the timestamp for 'now'
            will be used.

    Returns:
    Integer time since the epoch in milliseconds. If the supplied 'when' is
    None, the return value will be None.
    """
    if when is None:
        when = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    ms_since_epoch = float(time.mktime(when.utctimetuple()) * 1000.0)
    return {
        'seconds': int(ms_since_epoch),
        'nanos': int(when.microsecond / 1000.0),
    }

def setup_json_logger(suffix=''):
    try:

        from pythonjsonlogger import jsonlogger

        class GoogleJsonFormatter(jsonlogger.JsonFormatter):

            FORMAT_STRING = "{message}"

            def add_fields(self, log_record, record, message_dict):
                super(GoogleJsonFormatter, self).add_fields(log_record,
                                                            record,
                                                            message_dict)

                log_record['severity'] = record.levelname
                log_record['timestamp'] = get_timestamp_dict()
                log_record['message'] = self.FORMAT_STRING.format(
                                            message=record.message,
                                            filename=record.filename,
                                            )

        formatter = GoogleJsonFormatter()

        log_path = '/var/log/app_engine/custom_logs/worker'+suffix+'.log.json'
        make_sure_path_exists(log_path)
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_path)

        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logging.getLogger().addHandler(file_handler)

    except OSError:
        logging.warn("Custom log path not found for production logging")

    except ImportError:
        logging.warn("JSON Formatting not available")
```

To use, simply call `setup_json_logger` - you may also want to change the name of `worker` for your log.

Comment: Thanks, Josh! I haven't tried your answer yet, but I'm marking it as answer until I do. In the issue tracker of app engine you mention a lot of blank logs. Does that mean that there are still some issues with it?

Comment: @Arjen you are correct. I posted this because it's been Google's response, and it's "supposed" to work this way. I'll update the answer as I continue to make progress.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a NodeJS app running on a managed VM and I am also trying to get my logs to be printed on the Google Developper Console. I created my log files in the ‘/var/log/app_engine’ directory as described in the documentation. Unfortunately this doesn’t seem to be working for me, even for the ‘.log’ files.

Could you describe where your logs are created ? Also, is your managed VM configured as "Managed by Google" or "Managed by User" ? Thanks!

Comment: We write our logs to directory `/var/log/app_engine/custom_logs`. To simplify testing you can SSH into a VM instance, then use docker to start a bash prompt in the running image and then create the file `/var/log/app_engine/custom_logs/app.log` with some testdata. It doesn't matter if your VM is managed by Google or User.

Comment: Thanks a lot Arjen ! My problem was that I forgot to start a bash prompt with Docker. I was testing in the managed VM instead of the container... By the way here are the commands to start the docker prompt: "docker ps" to retrieve the id and then "docker exec -i -t <ID> bash". I can also confirm that the .log.json files aren't visible.

Comment: This issue was submitted to google a while back, please give it your +1s:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11678